# Edit each Character in ToCharArray?

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to make an HTML rainbow chat script where I ask for user input with read-host and then it takes that input (E.g "Testers will test") then it takes every letter and adds something before and after it that way I can have something like

```
[HTMLCODE]T</>[HTMLCODE]e</>[HTMLCODE]s</>[HTMLCODE]t</>
```

If the user inputted Test^

So far I have the worst script ever that only allows 50 characters and you have to use the 50 characters:

```
$FinalString = $rainbow.ToCharArray()
$Final = $r+$FinalString[0]+$y+$FinalString[1]+$g+$FinalString[2]+$b+$FinalString[3]+$p+$FinalString[4]+$r+$FinalString[5]+$r+$FinalString[7]+$y+$FinalString[8]+$g+$FinalString[9]+$b+$FinalString[10]+$p+$FinalString[11]+$r+$FinalString[12]+$r+$FinalString[13]+$y+$FinalString[14]+$g+$FinalString[15]+$b+$FinalString[16]+$p+$FinalString[17]+$r+$FinalString[18]+$r+$FinalString[19]+$y+$FinalString[20]+$g+$FinalString[21]+$b+$FinalString[22]+$p+$FinalString[23]+$r+$FinalString[24]+$r+$FinalString[25]+$y+$FinalString[26]+$g+$FinalString[27]+$b+$FinalString[28]+$p+$FinalString[29]+$r+$FinalString[30]+$r+$FinalString[31]+$y+$FinalString[32]+$g+$FinalString[33]+$b+$FinalString[34]+$p+$FinalString[35]+$r+$FinalString[36]+$r+$FinalString[37]+$y+$FinalString[38]+$g+$FinalString[39]+$b+$FinalString[40]+$p+$FinalString[41]+$r+$FinalString[42]+$r+$FinalString[43]+$y+$FinalString[44]+$g+$FinalString[45]+$b+$FinalString[46]+$p+$FinalString[47]+$r+$FinalString[48]+$r+$FinalString[49]+$y+$FinalString[50]

Write-Host $Final"
```

I have no idea if this is even possible and I feel like everything I thought I knew about PowerShell is gone. Even a point in the right direction would help I'm sure I'm missing something obvious.

EDIT: Here is what I made in Python as an example of what I'm trying to do but I need this in PS I've been trying to learn PowerShell

```
import pyperclip
def main():
t = input("What is the text you would like to colorfy!?: ")
c = "rainbow"
f = ['</>']
if c == ("rainbow"):
        d = 0
        e = list(t)
        for i in range (0,len(e)):
            if d == 4:
                f.append("<HTMLCODEEXAMPLE>"+e[i]+"</>")
                d = 0
            elif d == 3:
                f.append("<HTMLCODEEXAMPLE>"+e[i]+"</>")
                d = 4
            elif d == 2:
                f.append("<HTMLCODEEXAMPLE>"+e[i]+"</>")
                d = 3
            elif d == 1:
                f.append("<HTMLCODEEXAMPLE>"+e[i]+"</>")
                d = 2
            elif d == 0:
                f.append("<HTMLCODEEXAMPLE>"+e[i]+"</>")
                d = 1
        f.append("<HTMLCODEEXAMPLE></>")
        G = str(f)
        G = G.replace("[","")
        G = G.replace("]","")
        G = G.replace("'","")
        G = G.replace("[","")
        G = G.replace(", ","")
        print(G)
        pyperclip.copy(G)
        f.clear()
main()
main()
```

Comment: Please, when adding tags to your question, only add the [tag:powershell] tag that corresponds with your version

Answer (score 2):

If you want to cycle through a fixed number of items, use the remainder operator `%` to "wrap around" and go back to zero:

```
$word = 'Rainbow'
$colors = -split 'Red Orange Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet'

$htmlBuilder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()

for($i = 0; $i -lt $word.Length; $i++)
{
  # pick color, use % to wrap around at the end of the $colors array
  $color = $colors[$i % $colors.Length]

  # append html fragment
  $htmlBuilder = $htmlBuilder.AppendFormat('<span style="color: {0}">{1}</span>', $color, $word[$i])
}

# output html string
$htmlBuilder.ToString()
```

Which produces:

```html
<span style="color: Red">R</span><span style="color: Orange">a</span><span style="color: Yellow">i</span><span style="color: Green">n</span><span style="color: Blue">b</span><span style="color: Indigo">o</span><span style="color: Violet">w</span>
```

To show the color picker wrapping around and going back to red, here's the output with `$word = 'StackOverflow'`:

```html
<span style="color: Red">S</span><span style="color: Orange">t</span><span style="color: Yellow">a</span><span style="color: Green">c</span><span style="color: Blue">k</span><span style="color: Indigo">O</span><span style="color: Violet">v</span><span style="color: Red">e</span><span style="color: Orange">r</span><span style="color: Yellow">f</span><span style="color: Green">l</span><span style="color: Blue">o</span><span style="color: Indigo">w</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try, there is no need for a `for` loop in this case. You can use a `foreach` loop (`.foreach(..)` method in this case) to loop over each character and add your `$x` and `$y` tags on each element.

If you want all as single *string* instead of a *multi-line string*, use the `.Append(..)` method instead of `.AppendLine(..)` method of the [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-6.0).

**Note, this assumes that `$x` and `$y` have the same number of elements.**

```
$string = "Testers will test"
$x = '<tag1>', '<tag2>', '<tag3>', '<tag4>'
$y = '</tag1>', '</tag2>', '</tag3>', '</tag4>'
$i = 0
$builder = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$string.ToCharArray().ForEach({
    process {
        $null = $builder.AppendLine(('{0}{1}{2}' -f $x[$i], $_, $y[$i++]))
        if($i -eq $x.Count) { $i = 0 }
    }
    end {
        $builder.ToString()
    }
})
```

Comment: This is an amazing and quick response that points me in the right direction! I guess my only question would be how would I make it interval between each color code because I'd need like 5 HTMLCODE's applying letter by letter if that makes any sense. Because with this I can apply HTML code to each letter but only one HTML code whereas I need 5 colors going to each letter over and over. Thank you so much for the fast response

Comment: You're the best. I used it and it works but I honestly don't understand it haha